# dynamic form creation adding rows downward

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i need this kind of functionality

[image]

like one row added after an other i search a lot about it but getting a bit like stuf like in these websites

```
http://www.infotuts.com/dynamically-add-input-fields-to-form-jquery/
http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/2012/07/27/adding-form-fields-dynamically-with-jquery/
```

but fail to code(mean not able to convert like above). i am new to jquery and javascript anyone gives tutorial links or code or library. thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Datagrid](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid12_demo.html). I think it will fit on your requirements. You can change the design as you wish.